# Why has Wubi support been withdrawn?

Tags: wubi

Why has Wubi support been withdrawn from Ubuntu 12.10 onwards? Does Ubuntu 14.04 have Wubi support or not?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows installer for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS onwards](http://askubuntu.com/questions/449486/windows-installer-for-ubuntu-14-04-lts-onwards)

Answer (score 1):

Wubi is still available for newer versions, including 14.04. Go to this page: http://releases.ubuntu.com/   and choose the version you want. In the list of files at the bottom, the very last one will be wubi.exe. Grab that file and run it.

Answer (score 0):

Wubi is officially supported for Windows XP, Vista and 7.  It allows Ubuntu to be installed and uninstalled in a safe, easy way as with any other Windows application.

Now that Windows 8 came in play, Wubi does not work with Windows 8 default boot-loader. Thus at this point Wubi would not work on a new Windows 8 machine. You would be able to install, but not reboot into Ubuntu.

If you upgraded to Windows 8 and are using BIOS firmware, Wubi does work.  It will not be available in 14.04 as well.<sup>[WubiGuide](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide)</sup>

[Extra reading](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/wubi-advice)